# Disable external authentication on Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I run a bare-metal Kubernetes cluster and want to map services onto URLs instead of ports (I used `NodePort` so far).

To achieve this I tried to install an `IngressController` to be able to deploy Ingress objects containing routing.

I installed the `IngressController` via helm:

```
helm install my-ingress helm install my-ingress stable/nginx-ingress
```

and the deployment worked fine so far. To just use the node's domain name, I enabled `hostNetwork: true` in the `nginx-ingress-controller`.

Then, I created an Ingress deployment with this definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

which also deployed fine. Finally, when I try to access `http://my-url.com/testpath` I get a login-prompt. I nowhere set up login-credentials nor do I intend to do so as the services should be publicly available and/or handle authentication on their own.

How do I disable this behavior? I want to access the services just as I would use a `NodePort` solution.

Comment: That behavior is not coming from the ingress. It is possible to do basic auth with the ingress, but you need to configure that explicitly which you have not.

Comment: Do you have an idea where it's coming from? It doesnt happen when i uninstall the Helm deployment

Comment: Most likely from `my-service`.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: It turned out, another Ingress was already started during my deployment of Longhorn, which forced basic authentication onto the other one as well. I cleaned up all deployments and it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the case I am posting answer (from comments area) as Community Wiki.

The problem here was not in configuration but in environment - there was running another ingress in the pod during Longhorn' deployment. This situation led to force basic authentication to both ones.

To resolve that problem it was necessary to to clean up all deployments.